# How much heat can a demijohn take?

Tags: temperature, cider, glass

I'm planning to serve some homemade cider, hot and mulled at a market stall in the coming weeks. I'll be siphoning out of a 23L demijohn (like this: http://www.toowoombahomebrewers.com.au/Wine/Accessories/glass-demijohn-23-l to serve.

The plan is to heat the cider in a big pot to the right temperature (say, 70C), pour a little into the demi to let it adjust, then fill it up. I might need some sort of heat source to keep it warm, but I won't have power. I'm thinking about a very low gas flame with a lot of diffusion (fine metal screens) underneath the demi. Then again, 20L of hot liquid stays hot a long time, maybe I won't need to worry.

Am I mental? Am I going to explode the demi? We clean them with a hot-water pressure cleaner, and they're fine, but I wonder about having them full of hot liquid. Last thing I need is 23L of scalding cider exploding everywhere on the night.

Comment: hmm...two questions in a row of people taking risks with carboys because of cider! Must be potent stuff! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it. They are not meant to be heated. You could heat it before hand and put it into an insulated cooler, and that would hold the heat for a long time.

Comment: This, or use a small gas burner and a big pot to dispense it, I've had a lot of hot/warm cider, and it's never been carbonated, so you won't need to worry about this.

Anything that isn't heat/shock resistive glass (Pyrex, brosillicate, etc...) shouldn't be used with heat.

Comment: Doug, I ended up going with something like what you suggested: I tested the Demi with water at about 65C, with no problems, and it only dropped about 10C over 4 hours. On the night, I heated the cider in a stainless  keg, transferred it into the demi, and had a couple of large beakers on top of gas burners, which I siphoned into from the demi: Looked great - like a bit of a science experiment, and folks loved it. Sold about 30L of cider that way!